# Tracking the time since last keystroke?

Tags: python, keylogger

This is my completed keylogger as of right now. I have already posted this question before but it was really hard to iterate myself. On_press and On_release are the two main functions in this. They both track one keystroke. I need to track the time it takes between keystrokes, and I am not totally sure how I would get this done. I had the thought that I could track to see the time in between the string appends. I need to be able to see the time in between keystrokes because if that is longer than a certain period of time (ten seconds), I want the string which houses the keystrokes (keys) to be cleared. Thank y'all!

```
import pynput
import time 
import os, sys
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import psutil 

count = 0
keys = []

if (time.time() - lastKeystroke > 10):
   keys =[]

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    
    keys.append(str(key).replace("'",'').replace("Key.space", ' ').replace("Key.shift", "").lower())

    print(keys)

    count += 1
def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

lastKeystroke = time.time()

with Listener(on_press, on_release =on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: what is the problem to use variable ie. `previous_time` to keep time when previous function was executed and compare with current time? And after that assing current time as previous time to use it in next event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is minimal example to get time between any two pressed keys.

At start it sets `previous_time` with `time.time()` and when I press key then it get `current_time` and compare with `previous_time` to see time before first press. And later it keep `current_time` in `previous_time` to calculate it again when I press next key.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_press(key):
    global previous_time

    # get current time and calculate time between two pressed keys
    current_time = time.time()
    diff_time = current_time - previous_time

    print('seconds:', diff_time)
    
    # save current time for next calculation
    previous_time = current_time
    
    # use this value for something
    if diff_time > 10:
         print("Too late!")

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

# --- main ---

previous_time = time.time() # value as start

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```